# Hairy Ball Theorem: homotopy from the identity to the antipodal map

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, compact-manifolds

I'm having trouble to prove the following statement:

> If the $n$-sphere $S^n\subset\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ admits a (continuous) nonvanishing tangent vector field, then $n$ is odd.

The idea of the proof is pretty clear on my mind: we use the fact that the antipodal map has degree $(-1)^{n+1}$ and that the Brouwer degree is invariant under homotopies.

We have a (continuous) nonvanishing tangent vector field $v\colon S^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ that can be supposed unitary (otherwise, just consider $u=v/\|v\|$).
Paraphrasing Hirsch: "a homotopy of $S^n$ from the identity map to the antipodal map is obtained moving each $p\in S^n$ to $-p$ along the great semicircle in the direction $v(p)$".

My question is: *is there an explicit formula for this homotopy?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The application $H\colon S^n\times[0,1]\to S^n$ given by
$$H(x,t) = \cos(\pi t)x + \sin(\pi t) v(x)$$
is what I was looking for.

Comment: That will not stay in $S^n$.

Comment: @PVAL-inactive Well, for all $t\in[0,1]$ and all $x\in S^n$, we have that $\|\cos(\pi t)x + \sin(\pi t)v(x)\|^2 = \langle \cos(\pi t)x + \sin(\pi t)v(x), \cos(\pi t)x + \sin(\pi t)v(x) \rangle = \cos^2(\pi t)\|x\|^2 + \cos(\pi t)\sin(\pi t)\langle x,v(x)\rangle + \sin^2(\pi t)\|v(x)\|^2 = \cos^2(\pi t) + \sin^2(\pi t) = 1$, since $\|x\| = \|v(x)\| = 1$ and $\langle x,v(x) \rangle = 0$.

Answer (score 5):

How about this? Define $\Phi:S^n\times[0,1]\to S^n$, $n=2m-1$ by
$\Phi(v,t)=A(t)v$ where $A(t)$ is the matrix
$$\pmatrix{
\cos \pi t&\sin\pi t&&&&&&\\
-\sin \pi t&\cos\pi t&&&&&&\\
&&\cos \pi t&\sin\pi t&&&&\\
&&-\sin \pi t&\cos\pi t&&&&\\
&&&&\ddots&&&\\
&&&&&\cos \pi t&\sin\pi t\\
&&&&&-\sin\pi t&\cos\pi t\\
}.$$

Comment: Nice trick! But I have to prove that $n$ is odd, haven't I?

Comment: @rldias Lord Shark is thinking of $S^n$ as a subset of $\Bbb R^{n+1}$. There is a reason this construction only makes sense when $n$ is odd (i.e. when $n+1$ is even).